# HTML report of maven dependency update

Tags: maven-3

the command 'mvn versions:display-dependency-updates' gives the latest updates for my dependancies. 
Is there a way of getting a HTML report of the same? Something like

http://awhitford.github.io/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/dependency-updates-report.html

thanks in advance,
-anish

Answer (score 2):

Sorry folks - i should have a little more careful in reading the manual

```
mvn versions:dependency-updates-report
```

creates the HTML report while

```
 mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

prints to the console

Comment: I so kept screwing this up as well, even when I had thought I put in "report", I hadnt, double checked, oops.  This worked great
`versions:dependency-updates-report versions:plugin-updates-report` the reports are output to the "Site" folder under target.  Your answer made me sanity check, thanks!